# Improving performance on Mat pixel access in OpenCV

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, image-processing, profiling

I have the following function of code on my program

```
template <typename _Tp>
void lbp::OLBP_(const Mat& src, Mat& dst) {
    assert(src.rows > 3);
    dst = Mat::zeros(src.rows-2, src.cols-2, CV_8UC1);

    _Tp
        *row_m1,
        *row = (_Tp*)src.ptr<_Tp>(0),
        *row_p1 = (_Tp*)src.ptr<_Tp>(1);

    for(int i=1; i<src.rows-1; i++) {
        unsigned char *dst_row = dst.ptr<unsigned char>(i-1);
        row_m1 = row;
        row = row_p1;
        row_p1 = (_Tp*)src.ptr<_Tp>(i+1);

        for(int j=1;j<src.cols-1;j++) {
            _Tp center = row[j];
            unsigned char code = 0;
            code |= (row_m1 [j-1] > center) << 7;
            code |= (row_m1 [j]   > center) << 6;
            code |= (row_m1 [j+1] > center) << 5;
            code |= (row    [j+1] > center) << 4;
            code |= (row_p1 [j+1] > center) << 3;
            code |= (row_p1 [j]   > center) << 2;
            code |= (row_p1 [j-1] > center) << 1;
            code |= (row    [j-1] > center) << 0;
            dst_row[j-1] = code;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what it does is, for each pixel in `src` generates a code in `dst`. That "code" is a binary number where each one of its 8 bits correspond to each one of the 8 pixel's neighbors, a `1` if the neighbor is larger than the pixel in the center and `0` otherwise. (see [Local Binary Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) in Wikipedia)

The code works fine and its going to be called a very large number of times. Running a profiler I found out that most of the execution time was spent on this particular function, particularly on the lines where I access the pixel values:

```
//The code is templated but it should compile to something similar to this
unsigned char *pointer = src.ptr<unsigned char>(row); // THIS CONSUMES MOST OF THE TIME!
pointer[column]; // get the actual pixel value
```

**Is there any room for improvement on the way pixels are accessed?**
I'm particularly interested in scenarios like this where the function requires random access to the image and not so the sequential case.

Comment: ptr<> may not be the most effective way of pixel access, but it is reasonably effective. And it is called only once per row. It is EXTREMELY UNLIKELY that it consumes any notable part of run time. It is more probable that profiler is blaming wrong row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, **yes**. You can avoid calling `Mat::ptr` when writing data into the `dst` image:

```
...
for(int i=1; i<src.rows-1; i++) {
  unsigned char *dst_row = dst.ptr<unsigned char>(i-1); << THIS CAN BE AVOIDED      
...
```

You can simply initialize a pointer to the data buffer in `dst` after creating it and then filling it without calling `ptr`, i.e.:

```
dst = Mat::zeros(src.rows-2, src.cols-2, CV_8UC1);
unsigned char *dst_data = dst.data;
int pix_ctr = 0;

// .. and then, inside the `for` loop, after calculating the LBP code.

dst_data[pix_ctr++] = code;
```

This is possible **only** if the data stored in `dst` is **contiguous** (in this case you know it because you just initialized it by calling to `Mat::zeros`). You can check it by calling `dst.isContinuous()`.

(In fact, you could get rid of **all**  the `Mat::ptr` inside the loop if the input data in `src` is contiguous. In that case, advance your pixel pointers without `ptr` by using the image dimensions).